# how to find valency of calcium using spdf electronic configuration

Tags: electronic-configuration

Electronic configuration of calcium is $\ce{1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 4s^2}$. The orbitals are fully filled with electrons so would its valency be two or zero?

Comment: The configuration $$1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 4s^2$$ has a valency of zero since there are as many electrons as protons. The configuration $$1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 $$ is two electrons short, so it has a valency of +2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the valency is 2. It's all orbitals are completely filled, but it's outer most orbit is incomplete. Ca can easy donate 2 electrons and can become stable cation.